# How to exclude files names that have exact match with regex and to support multiple patterns?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I have a program that transfers files from one folder to another (and does some manipulation on those files),
I am trying to create a regex to exclude certain files based on file name and extension, this also needs to support multiple entries that users enter the exclude patterns they want like -
    exclude pattern: thumbs.db ; donotmove.xls ; *.ini;

I have a folder with the following c:\testfolder:

```
test.txt
test.exe
something.jpg
other.pdf
```

Above should be moved (could be any file)
Below should not be moved (could be anything that the user specifies in config

```
thumbs.db
donotmove.xlsx
```

The goal is to exclude unwanted files like thumbs.db, and other files that the user will want to exclude (the code is already written, I am just having trouble with the regex itself).

I have been able to create a regex that will capture thumbs.db, but I have not been able to successfully add a negative lookahead into the regex.

The regex I have is:

```
^[Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss]\.[Dd][Bb]$
```

this captures thumbs.db exactly meaning if I have a file with this name "tthumbs.db" it should not capture the file name.

1. first problem I have is not being able to use negative lookhead to exclude the string
   I have tried the following:

   ^(?![Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss].[Dd][Bb])$
   ^(?![Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss]).(?![Dd][Bb])$
   ^(?![Tt])(?![Hh])(?![Uu])(?![Mm])(?![Bb])(?![Ss])).(?![Dd])(?![Bb])$
2. second problem I have is not being able to correctly use capturing group to capture multiple strings in one regex, I tried to add another capture group but adding does not capture anything

   ^([Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss].[Dd][Bb])([Tt][Ee][Ss][Tt].[Tt][Xx][Tt])$

thnx in advance.

Comment: `^(?!(?:foo|bar|[Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss]\.[Dd][Bb]|etc)$)`?

Comment: `^(?!(?i:file1|file2|thumbs\.db|fileN)$)` - Why don't you use the 'i' (ignoring case) flag?

Comment: in case the duplicates don't help you for the capturing part, you can do this (using case insensitive, negative lookaheads, alternation and escaping the dots): `^((?!(?:thumbs\.db$|test\.txt$)).*)` (i assume you wanted to capture the files that are not your reserved ones, was writing an answer as question got closed, i don't usually answer in comments)

Comment: Hi thank you very much, I did not see the duplicated question (sorry), I used @shadowsheep answer and ended with ^(?!(?i:thumbs\.db|text\.txt)$) which works great. thank you all :)